Set ECDLP complexity
Consider the following problem which is an easier version of the EC discrete log problem. Fix an elliptic curve and a generator $G$. Given an arbitrary set of points $S$, the task is to find $k$ such that $kG \in S$.
If $|S| =1$ this is the ECDLP and admits a $O(\sqrt{n})$ solution. On the other extreme, when $|S|=n$, any k works.
Does this problem have a name? Can we achieve $\sqrt{n/s}$?


Does this problem have a name? Can we achieve $\sqrt{n/s}$?

That would be termed the 'multitarget discrete log' problem, however it is uninteresting.  That's because, for any $s \lll \sqrt{n}$, the work is still $O( \sqrt{n} )$.
Here's why: suppose we had an $s$ where we could solve the multitarget discrete log problem in time $\alpha_s \lll \sqrt{n}$.  Then, what we could do is, to solve a simple discrete problem $kG$ is generate $s$ random values $r_1, r_2, ..., r_s$, and compute $r_1(kG), r_2(kG), ..., r_s(kG)$.  Those are $s$ random points, and so we can hand it off to our multitarget solver, which gives us the value $x$ with $xG = r_i(kG)$ for some $i$.  Then, we have $k = x r_i^{-1}$, giving us the solution to the original discrete log problem.
The amount of time taken is the time $O(s)$ to generate the random values and multiply $kG$ by them, and the time taken to do our multitarget solver $\alpha_s$ (and a tiny amount of time to do the modular inverse at the end; that's tiny).
If $s + \alpha_s < \sqrt{n}$ (and we assumed that both $s$ and $\alpha_s$ are much smaller than $\sqrt{n}$), then we have an alternative algorithm to solve the ECDLP problem faster, and we don't believe there is one.

Thank you! This is a powerful reduction that applies to all kinds of problems: Any pair discrete log, output distinct $i,j,k$ and scalars $a,b$ such that $aP_i+bP_j = P_k$ etc.
